# Absolute URL's acting like relative URL's

Tags: html, url, href

When I have a link like http://site.com, clicking it goes to that URL just fine.

But when the link is just `www.site.com`, it adds this URL to the parent website and consequently does not go to the URL.

So, clicking on `<a href='www.site.com'>site</a>` creates this in the browser taskbar: `www.parentsite.com/www.site.com`.

How can I fix this without using `preg_replace`? I am fairly new to this game.

Comment: you have to include `http://www`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `www.parentsite.com` is interpreted as a *relative address*, like for example `index.htm`, as opposed to an absolute URL which consists of protocol, hostname, and path.

When I'm on `example.com`'s front page....

- `contact.html` is a relative address, the absolute end result will be `http://example.com/contact.html` (the browser does this as an internal calculation)
- `images/` is a relative address, resulting in `http://example.com/images/`
- `www.xyz.com` results in `http://example.com/www.xyz.com`

You need to prefix the protocol (eg. `http://`) to make the browser understand that you mean a full URL, and treat it accordingly.

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208688%28v=office.12%29.aspx) a background info article on the issue on MSDN.