# Absolute URLs behave like relative URLs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

I have a bunch of links in the footer of my app (Angular 1.3.15).

**html**

```
<section class="footer-projects">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <section ng-repeat="area in ::links">
                    <h4 ng-bind="area.title"></h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="project in ::area.projects">
                            <a href="{{project.url}}" ng-bind="project.name"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

`ng-repeat` loops through this

**js constants**

```
'use strict';

require('./footer.module.js')
    .constant('FooterLinkConstants', [
        {
            title: 'Space',
            projects: [
                {
                    name: 'Galaxy Zoo',
                    url: 'http://www.galaxyzoo.org/'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Moon Zoo',
                    url: 'http://www.moonzoo.org/'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Solar Storm Watch',
                    url: 'http://www.solarstormwatch.com/'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Planet Hunters',
                    url: 'http://planethunters.org/'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Planet Four',
                    url: 'http://planetfour.org/'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Radio Galaxy Zoo',
                    url: 'http://radio.galaxyzoo.org/'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Stardate M83',
                    url: 'http://www.projectstardate.org/'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Disk Detective',
                    url: 'http://diskdetective.org/'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]);
```

and this is my directive

**js directive**

```
'use strict';

require('./footer.module.js')
    .directive('appFooter', appFooter);

// @ngInject
function appFooter($state, FooterLinkConstants) {
    var directive = {
        link: appFooterLink,
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'footer/footer.html'
    };
    return directive;

    function appFooterLink(scope) {
        scope.links = FooterLinkConstants;
        });
    }
}
```

All works fine in development. However when I deploy to a remote server address, that address gets prepended to the values in my list above. For example:

instead of

`http://www.galaxyzoo.org/`

I get

`http://preview.zooniverse.org/folgerdemo/http://galaxyzoo.org/`

You can have a look at the [live example](http://preview.zooniverse.org/folgerdemo/#/) (just inspect the links in the footer)

So why does that happen?

Other questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276021/absolute-urls-acting-like-relative-urls), suggest to use absolute urls by including the protocol in the addresses; which I am already doing.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious, but could do with some fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: Try using `ng-href` instead of `href` directly in your template

Comment: @MikeVranckx just deployed the template with ng-href and no joy.

Comment: @Visualife why would using the api help? `window.location.href` just returns the current url.

Comment: This is really baffling. Are you using any other libraries that could be interfering with href attribute assignment? Could you provide a smaller example, or at least an unminified one?

Comment: Maybe your HTML is escaped, try using an html filter on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right. Unfortunately only I could know the answer - not because it was difficult obviously, but because I didn't provide all the pieces of information in my question.

I built my application as a spin-off of somebody else's. The app uses Gulp as task manager.

It turns out that this line

`gulp.src(filename).pipe(replace(/(href=")(?![http|\/\/])/g, '$1' + prefix))`,

where `prefix` value is dependent on the type of  AWS S3 bucket is used, was replacing my urls.

Once I commented out that line, things were back to normal.

Thanks to people who commented and apologies for wasting your time ;)